# Revert to normal recovery mode from CWM recovery mode

Tags: custom-roms, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, restore, stock-rom

I am using Micromax Canvas 2.2.

I wanted to install a custom ROM on it, so I backed up the the original ROM (normally, without using CWM recovery). After that, I installed CWM recovery mode on it. Then, I wiped my data & cache and installed a custom ROM, but I forgot to backup the previous ROM using CWM! Now, when I wanted to restore the previous ROM, it is impossible!

The previous backup is a `.backup` file & CWM can't restore it. I have to restore it via normal recovery mode, but whenever I turn on recovery mode, CWM mode automatically comes there! How to restore my previous ROM?

Comment: so, are you trying to "go back to stock"?
try to find nand backup of it somewhere, then restore it with CWM, and then restore your backup in the stock ROM

Answer (score 1):

Just flash stock `recovery.img` file through [Mobile uncle tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileuncle.toolbox).
But in case you want your stock rom back, this will not be helpful to you.
You will have to flash stock firmware through mtk droid tools.